# Linq to SQL Strange SQL Translation

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, c#-4.0

I have a simple query that is generating some odd SQL translations, which is blowing up my code when the object is saturated.

```
from x in DataContext.MyEntities
select new 
{
    IsTypeCDA = x.EntityType == "CDA" 
}
```

I would expect this query should translate to:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN [t0].[EntityType] = @p1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [IsTypeCDA]
...
```

Instead I get this :

```
SELECT 
(CASE 
    WHEN @p1 = [t0].[EntityType] THEN 1
    WHEN NOT (@p1 = [t0].[EntityType]) THEN 0
    ELSE NULL
 END) AS [IsTypeCDA]
...
```

Since I'm saturating a POCO where `IsTypeCDA` is a `bool`, it blows up stating I can't assign `null` to `bool`.

Any thoughts?

**Edit:** fixed the property names so they make sense...

Comment: Is `DOCUMENT_TYPE` the column the `EntityType` property is mapped to? It looks like you muddied the waters when you cleaned up the generated SQL.

Comment: Of what type is the `MyEntities` property and of what type is `EntityType.CDA`?

Comment: zinglon : I muddied the waters, when I translated from my query to a more readable example for the post, DOCUMENT_TYPE is the actual column, and it's mapped correctly, I've edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Steven : yeah I messed up when I was writing the post I've fixed it. `MyEntities` is a table, `MyEntities.EntityType` is a string `EntityType` is a static class and `EntityType.CDA` is a constant string.  basically `MyEntities.EntityType` can be any of n values, but only a handful are important in the scope of this query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from x in DataContext.MyEntities
select new
{
  IsTypeCDA = x.EntityType == null 
}
```

c# interpretation (false) or sql interpretation (null)?

This runs in sql so sql interpretation.  That's why the funky translation - the operation does return a nullable bool.

Use this query to punt that nullable bool into a plain old bool.

```
from x in DataContext.MyEntities
select new
{
  IsTypeCDA = ((bool?)(x.EntityType == "CDA")) ?? false
}
```

Comment: Doing it this way keeps the generated SQL free of funky null handling. I think I like it better than my solutions. +1

Answer (score 1):

Linq to SQL does the "strange" comparison because database values can be `NULL`. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to do well translating the tri-valued comparison result. At first blush, I'd wonder why any of your entities have `NULL` for their `EntityType`. Modifying your schema to disallow `NULL` values would be the most straightforward solution.

However, assuming the table is defined this way for legitimate business reasons you can work around it in a couple ways.

First off, you could coalesce the `NULL`s into a placeholder value.

```
from x in DataContext.MyEntities
select new 
{
    IsTypeCDA = (x.EntityType ?? "") == "CDA" 
}
```

Alternately, using `String.Equals` generates a more thorough comparison that handles `NULL`s.

```
from x in DataContext.MyEntities
select new 
{
    IsTypeCDA = string.Equals(x.EntityType, "CDA")
}
```

Neither of these will generate the simple SQL you were expecting, but they'll both get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

I would have `IsTypeCDA` as a get only property and select into that class:

```
public class SomeName
{
    public string EntityType { get; set; }
    public bool IsTypeCDA { get { return EntityType == EntityType.CDA; } }
}
```

...

```
from x in DataContext.MyEntities
select new SomeName
{
    EntityType = x.EntityType
}
```

Comment: Not a bad solution, however the resulting `IQueryable` can be composed in query, which uses that value, and since those `get` properties can't be translated to SQL it blows up.